# how convert sql to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How do I do this

Select top 10 Foo from MyTable

```
SELECT        TOP (30) Item, Descripcion, SUM(Amount) AS Suma         
FROM            Venat 
GROUP BY Item, Descripcion                          
ORDER BY Suma
```

in Linq to SQL?

with this only agrup by Item but not Description

```
var filtroprimeros30 = from nuevo in registrosVipDosAños
                     group nuevo by nuevo.Item into g         
                       select new
                        {
                            Item = g.Key,
                            Suma = g.Sum(nuevo => nuevo.Amount)

                        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anonymous type for grouping:

```
var filtroprimeros30 = 
     (from nuevo in registrosVipDosAños
      group nuevo by new { nuevo.Item, nuevo.Description } into g  // here    
      select new {
          g.Key.Item,
          g.Key.Description,
          Suma = g.Sum(n => n.Amount)
      })
     .OrderBy(x => x.Suma)
     .Take(30);
```

---

I'd actually go this way (because query syntax has nice syntax for grouping, but do not have ability to take N items):

```
var items = from n in registrosVipDosAños
            group n by new { n.Item, n.Description } into g
            select new {
              g.Key.Item,
              g.Key.Description,
              Suma = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
            };

var topItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Suma).Take(30);
```

Query still will be executed only once, but now it's more readable.

Comment: What about adding `orderby g.Sum(n => n.Amount)` between group and select?

Comment: @Aducci generated SQL will contain two `Sum(Amount)` columns in that case - one for ordering, and one for result. (according to LinqPad)

Comment: @user1178740 what `donts work` means? Exception? If you want to have items with biggest sum, you need to do `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy` (same relates to you SQL)

Answer (score 1):

syntax alternative

```
var filtroprimeros30 =  registrosVipDosAnos
                        .GroupBy(m => new {m.Item, m.Description})
                        .Select(g => new {
                           Item = g.Key.Item,
                           Description = g.Key.Description,
                           Suma = g.Sum(n => n.Amount)
                        })
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Suma)
                        .Take(30);
```